# How to include runtime dependency in jar generated from gradle jar task

Tags: java, gradle

I am creating a fat jar using gradle, build.gradle is as below:

```
...
dependencies {  

    compile files('local_path1')
    compile files('local_path2')  
    runtime files('local_path3')
}

task customFatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'MyMainClass'
    }
    archiveName = 'my-jar'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

Now, once I run the "customFatJar" task, the jar generated contains dependent jars in paths "local_path1" and "local_path2". But the jar generated does not contain dependent jar in path "local_path3".

Please let me know correct dependency configuration to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you defined the `local_path3` as `runtime`, you would need to add them into the script, too. Currently it just collecting all the `runtime` libs. It may looks like:

```
from { configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at the documentation around the [configurations created by the Java plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/5.0/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_plugin_and_dependency_management) and how they relate to each other.

In order to not miss a single *runtime* dependency in your fat jar, you should rely on the `runtimeClasspath` configuration:

```
from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
```